# How to compare magento version programmatically?

Tags: magento

I am trying to compare magento version so I can check if the current version is greater then 1.6 use the code otherwise don't.
I can get the magento version by using `Mage::getVersion()` and it returns `1.7.0.2` (a string) but how do I compare it so that my code won't break the page when installed on another magento whose version lower then this? Is there any other way better than this. solution must be from within magento.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `version_compare` function.

```
$magentoVersion = Mage::getVersion();
if (version_compare($magentoVersion, '1.6', '>=')){
    //version is 1.6 or greater
} 
else {
    //version is below 1.6
}
```

Comment: thats the one i'm looking for!

Comment: @marius Thanks its very useful for us +1

Answer (score 1):

```
if(version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.7.0.2') > 0)
```